# How was cholestyramine discovered?

Tags: biochemistry

How were the properties of bile acid sequestrants like cholestyramine discovered? The earliest reference to the chemical I could find was the following article which does not discuss the history of the drug:

Glueck CJ, Fallat R, Tsang R. Pediatric familial type II hyperlipoproteinemia: therapy with diet and cholestyramine resin. Pediatrics. 1973; 52:669-79. [IDIS 37416] [PubMed 4355362]

Does this kind of drug exist in nature or is it purely synthetic?

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely synthetic, a trimethyl-ammonium derivative of polystyrene.

The first to use it as a human medication seems to be Stanley S. Bergen, Jr. et al.

See [Effect of an Ion Exchange Resin on Serum Cholesterol in Man](http://nutritionreviews.oxfordjournals.org/content/42/4/164) *Proceedings of the Society for Experimental Biology and Medicine*, Volume 102, 1959, Pages 676–679:

> It is well known that bile acids are a major
>   end product of cholesterol metabolism and
>   that cholesterol is probably the only precursor
>   of bile acids([references]1-3 ) . Rate of oxidation of cholesterol
>   to bile acids is believed to be regulated
>   by need for bile acids for digestive purposes,
>   cholesterol normally being oxidized at
>   a rate sufficient to replace the bile acid that
>   escapes reabsorption and is lost in the feces
>   ([references] 4 - 5). If an agent could be found that would
>   sequester bile acids and thereby promote their
>   excretion in the feces, 2 consequences of clinical
>   interest might be anticipated: (1) increase
>   in rate of oxidative degradation of cholesterol.
>   and (2) decrease in serum cholesterol level.
>   Tennent ([reference] 6) described lowering of serum cholesterol
>   levels in animals fed the chloride salt
>   of a basic anion exchange resin. This material
>   (MK-135) has marked affinity for bile
>   acids *in vitro* and is believed to exert its serum
>   cholesterol-lowering effect by virtue of this
>   property( 6 ) . The present report summarizes
>   results obtained when MK 135 was administered
>   to 26 patients, many with elevated serum
>   cholesterol levels.

Reference 6 is Tennent, D. M., Siegel, H., Zanetti, M. E., Kuron, C. W., Ott, W. H., Wolf, F. J., *Circulation*, 1959, v20, 996.

Even though Bergen's paper only uses the term "MK 135", according to the editor's note on the current online version, this paper is the first use of cholestyramine as a medication in humans.